# How to get qtoolbars order

Tags: qt, qtoolbar

I need to save and restore position of QToolbars in my application.
When toolbars are docked to different area, i am able to save the area and assign it in function QMainWindow::addToolBar. But when several toolbars are docked to the same area, i don't know in what order they are currently on the screen.
I tried

```
QList<QToolBar*> toolbars = findChildren<QToolBar*>();
```

But this seems to return toolbars in order of creation and not how there are currently arranges on the screen (user can move them).

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy and straightforward way of doing what you want in Qt. `QMainWindow` has a method `saveState()` that

> saves the current state of this mainwindow's toolbars and dockwidgets.

and a method `restoreState()` that does the opposite.

Further information can be found [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qmainwindow.html#saveState).

To save and restore the `QMainWindow`'s geometry itself you can still use `QWidget::saveGeometry()` and `QWidget::restoreGeometry()`.

An example of both combined that can also be found in `saveState()`'s documentation:

> To save the geometry when the window closes, you can implement a close
>   event like this:
>
> ```
> void MyMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
> {
>     QSettings settings("MyCompany", "MyApp");
>     settings.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
>     settings.setValue("windowState", saveState());
>     QMainWindow::closeEvent(event);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But i would like to save UI state as human readable strings in ini file and not as a binary data.

Comment: My recommendation is to dig deep in the Qt source code then. :) (You know where to start)